# GCE API Required 'compute.zones.list' permission for 'projects/someproject'

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have created project in GCP. Then i create service account with ComputeAdmin role. Then i enable "Compute Engine API" for project.

But can't work with instances:

> #gcloud compute instances list
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.list) Some requests did not succeed: - Required 'compute.zones.list'
>   permission for 'projects/someproject'

what am I doing wrong ?

**Edited**

---

from service account:

> ERROR: (gcloud.projects.get-iam-policy) User
>   [cloud66@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have permission
>   to access project [project_id:getIamPolicy] (or it may not exist): The
>   caller does not have permission

When i switch to main google account:

> $ gcloud projects get-iam-policy project_id bindings:
>
> - members:
>
>   - serviceAccount:cloud66@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>
>   role: roles/compute.admin
> - members:
>
>   - serviceAccount:service-855312803173@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
>
>   role: roles/compute.serviceAgent
> - members:
>
>   - serviceAccount:855312803173-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
>   - serviceAccount:855312803173@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
>
>   role: roles/editor
> - members:
>
>   - user:my_google_user   role: roles/owner

From Logs view:

> 2020-01-28 16:46:30.932 EET Compute Engine list zones
>   cloud66@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com PERMISSION_DENIED
>
> code: 7
>   message:  "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time I created a service account "cloud66" in the Google test period. Most likely, this affected the access rights. Then I switched billing from a test period to a paid one. I deleted and recreated the cloud66 service account in the "APIs & Services -> Credentials" section. But there was an access policy for "cloud66" with the role of "ComputeAdmin" in the "IAM" section. When I deleted the access policy from the "IAM" section and recreated the service account, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) first. Usually such error occurs if your service account doesn't have enough permissions. In this case, you should [check available roles](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam), search there for required permission like `compute.zones.` and add it to your service account as it described [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts). For example it could be [`Compute Instance Admin (v1) role`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.instanceAdmin.v1).

**EDIT** It look like `Compute Admin role` should work for you. To be sure, check granted roles in your project with command:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy YOUR_PROJECT_ID
```

If want to use your service account with Cloud API from some application have a look at this [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started).

**EDIT2** Try to check your service account and key from 3rd place (like some linux desktop or server) as it described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication).

Comment: It has  ComputeAdmin role

Comment: I have updated my question with the gcloud command result. As you can see  "serviceAccount:cloud66" has the role "roles/compute.admin"

Comment: Yes, command output looks good. Do you use Cloud66 service https://www.cloud66.com/ or your service account named in such way for other reason? Please provide more details about your use case.

Comment: yes,  i am trying  add GCE as cloud provider in https://app.cloud66.com/clouds

Comment: also, i have already done theese actions for another project(with another google account) without any problems.

Comment: I found this instruction https://help.cloud66.com/rails/how-to-guides/clouds/cloud-gce.html. Did you use it? Have you imported GCE keys as it's described in the instruction? If yes, try to recreate service account and keys at GCE side and redo necessary steps at Cloud66.

Comment: I recreated service account with keys at GCE side and i still have this problem :-(

Comment: Okay, it looks like related to your project at GCE or to your app at Cloud66. I'd recommend you contact support https://cloud.google.com/support/ and http://app.cloud66.com/support_tickets/new and ask for assistance.

Comment: cloud66 sends me to google support, because the problem with CGE permissions. But  GCE  tech support is not free :-(

Comment: Try to check Stackdriver -> Logging -> Logs view. There could be some clues.

Comment: From Logs view:

2020-01-28 16:46:30.932 EET Compute Engine list zones cloud66@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com PERMISSION_DENIED 
code:  7     
message:  "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Comment: Try to check your service account and key from 3rd place (like some linux desktop or server) as it described in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#verifying_authentication. If you succeeded, it could be an argument for Cloud66 Support that issue actually on their side.

Comment: I have solved the problem after i remove policy from IAM for cloud66 and then i recreated it(early i removed clud66 only from Service Account). Thank you very much for your time!